# Reopen apt-get upgrade file compare dialog

Tags: debian, apt

I was doing an apt-get upgrade thought kitty, after getting the new php5 package it showed a set of choices to deal with the differences in the php.ini I had and the one it was going to add.

One of them was to open a new shell to deal with it, which I did.

But now I don't know how to get back to the dialogue to continue the upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Just exit the shell, type `exit` or press `CTRL-D`.

Comment: that just killed the kitty session